# Win10 keeps trying installing "English (US) Speech Recognition" and fails

Tags: windows-10, speech-recognition

Since a few days Windows 10 constantly nags me with an error message "Something happened, and we couldn't install a feature".

By clicking on the error message I am brought to Manage Optional Features. The History lists several failed attempts to install `English (US) Speech Recognition`. The install fails with error 0x80070422 (terse as usual, thanks Microsoft).

Hence the questions:

- Why is Windows 10 trying to install this component? I haven't asked for it and it will be of little use to me.
- What does the error mean (i.e. Why the install fails)?
- How do I tell Windows to give up?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 0x80070422 was caused by the Windows Update service being disabled. I've reenabled the service and this feature now installs correctly.

Comment: How did you do this?